# Connecting Two Analog Sources to One Analog Sink

Tags: audio, analog, speakers, voltage-source

**Q:** Connecting Two Analog Sources to One Analog Sink without the sources effecting one other

**What I want to do:**

I basically want to add a radio tuner/MP3 player in a car. Now, that car already has a Cassette Player (Kenwood KRC-265 [[Link]](http://manual.kenwood.com/files/B64-2102-00.pdf)). This cassette player (aliased CP hence forth) is not to be removed. So the option is to just add one.

**Problem**

Now the problem is that the CP has no AUX in nor the MP3 Player has an AUX out. So the only option is to share speakers (4) between the two.

**Possible Solutions**

- If I directly join the wires in a **Y join** directly then the voltage can sink into the circuit of the other and cause damage.
- If I add a diode (on + speaker line) to avoid a back flow, then the analog signal may get cut due to the diode's **0.7V drop**. The current can exceed an amp or two so I don't know if a germanium diode will do good (having low voltage drop).

I need you guys' advice on what to do.

Regards

**EDIT:**

Due to the lack of a word in my vocab. I used the word MP3 Player. It's a Car MP3 Player with built-in amp. Something like this: [Link to AliExpress](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Low-price-high-quality-Car-audio-MP3-Player-WMA-WAV-MP3-digital-display-FM-USB-SD/32748133234.html?spm=2114.search0104.3.24.u36alA&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_4_10152_10065_10151_10068_10084_10083_10080_10082_10081_10110_10137_10175_10111_10060_10112_10113_10155_10114_10154_438_10056_10055_10054_10310_10182_10059_9995_100031_10099_10078_10079_10103_10073_10102_5360020_10052_10053_10142_10107_10050_10051-10152_9995,searchweb201603_13,ppcSwitch_5&btsid=1188ce83-ad13-405e-aea3-36ee7a6b1c4d&algo_expid=7f0e07a0-2c15-41b2-b6d8-2ab8cc7513f4-3&algo_pvid=7f0e07a0-2c15-41b2-b6d8-2ab8cc7513f4)

But due to @Marcus Miller's answer providing me a better approach, I am planning to use that. That did come to my mind but failing to see that it is a 13 Pin connector (I assumed it was a CD Changer - a single signal/single wire connection), I did not google.

Comment: A diode would also not work (unless you provide your circuit with a sufficient DC forward bias, similar to RF switches using diodes) because your audio is an AC signal. 
If you are trying to say you want to connect your MP3 player directly to your car speakers - don't. It will not have the power to drive those speakers anyways. Perhaps it is better to look if you can add a way to inject the mp3 signal where the tape-player is connected?

Comment: There's these "casette adapters", basically things in the shape of a casette with a small coil mimicking the passing of a magentic tape, and a cable with a 3.55mm plug at the end. Sound is crappy, but so is the sound of car stereos with only a casette player.

Comment: Another option would be a separate power amplifier, but that may be more involved than the OP wants to get involved in.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I have that, too lossy.

Comment: @IanBland That MP3 has a builtin amp, not that powerful though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your CP probably *does* have an AUX input, but it's hiding as the CD changer control plug.

You can reverse-engineer that. In fact, a solid 12 seconds on google revealed this gem from http://nodivisions.com/tech/kenwood_aux_adapter/:

[image: adapter]

With that, you can simply select the CD changer as audio input to the CP and be done with it.

Comment: Can I connect an **amped** signal to that connection?

Comment: BTW forgot to say. If this works the way I want it to work, then I am going to find you and I will thank you xD

Answer (score 3):

Marcus has answered the audio part of your question. I'll address the "analog sink" part.

You are borrowing terms from digital logic and applying them to analog amplifiers.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fv7CWf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Common collector outputs allow simple 'OR' paralleling.*

The scheme of Figure 1 is common in TTL logic, and comparitor outputs, etc.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyxDts.png)</sup>

*Figure 2. Push-pull amplifier output configuration (highly simplified).*

The audio amplifiers have feedback which corrects any errors in the output voltage. If Amplifier 1 has no audio input then it will try to maintain zero volts on the output. If the output voltage reads a bit high it will turn on Q2 more and more to try to pull it down. If it's a bit low Q1 will turn on to try and pull the output higher.

Now consider what happens if Amplifier 2 is pumping out music. The amplifiers will fight to the death of one or other amplifier to control the voltage. More than likely the first transistor to die will fail short circuit pulling the output hard high or low. The remaining amplifier will fight this and the opposite transistor on the second amplifier will then die.

Some logic devices such as CMOS logic and micro controller GPIOs have similar output stages although in these cases they only switch fully high or low. Connecting these in parallel is a bad idea too.

> If I directly join the wires in a Y join directly then the voltage can sink into the circuit of the other and cause damage.

Correct.

> If I add a diode (on + speaker line) to avoid a back flow, then the analog signal may get cut due to the diode's 0.7V drop.

Not only a 0.7 V drop on positive going signals but complete blockage of negative going signals. The result would be horrendous distortion.

Comment: The phantom down-voter strikes again. Please explain why this does not answer the question with the limitations explained in the first line.

Comment: I will upvote it as it is a good answer - if I could upvote it twice I would....

Comment: @Transistor thank you for such detailed explanation. I was assuming the analog signal to be positive like minimum point being 0V. Thank you for clearing up the theory. :)

Answer (score 2):

> Possible Solutions

1. cassette adapter
2. FM adapter
3. if you have to hardware, think about a small resistor (1k-ish) + DC blocking capacitor.
4. an externally mounted switch might be a cleaner solution from a sound quality perspective.

Comment: 1. Tried that. Not the best, it is the most ridiculous sound quality.
2. FM tried that, same. To much loss of quality
3. May be
4. Want to avoid that.
Thank you :)